# python direct.actor.Actor animations are strechy

Tags: python, panda3d

[unsmooth animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/581Ek.png)

to fix animations and render proper model. When i run animation it become to strechy like shown in image, so i want it to run without any strechiness.

```
from ursina import *
from direct.actor.Actor import Actor

app = Ursina()
EditorCamera()
sky = Sky()

entity = Entity()
animations are stored within the file
actor = Actor("corgi/scene.gltf")
actor.reparent_to(entity)
actor.setScale(0.009) # Scale down by a factor of 10
actor.setPos(0, -95, 0) # Move down by 5 units on the Y-axis

print(actor.getAnimNames())

actor.loop("Idle") 

app.run()
```

this is my code in which i used panda 3D and ursina so please help me out please help with it.